# How to change the "width" of Selected Item in DropDownList using Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, drop-down-menu, selected

I have been searching to find out how to change the `width` of `@Html.DropDownList` for the selected item without any success. For design purposes, I would like to set it to `450px`, but it seems it doesn't go above `300`. Would that be a limitation?

```
@Html.DropDownList("AddressID", null, htmlAttributes: new { style = "width:450px" })
```

It seems that `new { style="width:450px" }` only changes the width of the options; not the selected area. While researching, I found out how to change the `height` of selected item by using `size` as in `new { size="20" }`. So I tried using `new { width = "450" }` but no success. `Length` also doesn't work. :(

I would appreciate any help I could get. Thanks!

Comment: are you using Bootstrap ? make sure there are no other CSS rules applied.

Answer (score 5):

in case you are using Bootstrap there are `max-width` rule applied to the `Select` Tag.

try this it worked for me:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AddressID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control", style = "width:450px;max-width:450px;" })
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks, man! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will vote your answer up once I have enough reputation.

Comment: Voted up as promised (now I have reputation for that) :)

Comment: @Fabricio WOW! it's almost 5 YEARS! Very happy that you kept your promise!